Is there an equivalent to the 902-928 MHz ISM band for Europe?
Is there a band for Europe that is similar to the North/South American ISM band (902 MHz - 928 MHz) where custom short-range wireless signals (~100m or less, under 10 dBm) can be used without any license?
A wikipedia page pertaining to short-range devices as well as a Texas instruments document** shows some frequencies and their usages, as shown below.
If one were to maintain the lowest-common denominator of requirements, i.e.: 0.1% duty cycle, and below 10 mW, could the whole range of frequencies from 863 MHz to 868 MHz be used as an ISM-equivalent band?
**(2005, Texas Instruments, "ISM-Band and Short Range Device Regulatory Compliance")



For region 1 (Europe/Middle East/Africa), the closest ISM band is 433MHz. The ~868MHz ish bands are available typically for wireless microphone applications.

The sources below seems to mention usable frequencies that don't need a license across 6 sub-bands from 863 MHz to 870 MHz, provided the limits are adhered to. Isn't this basically ISM but with more rules attached to it? // https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/lorawan/regional-parameters/eu868/ // https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300200_300299/30022002/03.02.01_60/en_30022002v030201p.pdf // https://www.disk91.com/2017/technology/sigfox/all-what-you-need-to-know-about-regulation-on-rf-868mhz-for-lpwan/
